# Unittesting Nlog's archive feature

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nlog

In my project I have created a logging system which is basically a shell on top of nLog. I am trying to unittest the archive feature of the logging system. It is currently setup to do rolling archives with a max archive files of 5 (Nlog is setup via code, no configuration file is used):

```
var myFileTarget = new FileTarget();
LogConfig.AddTarget("file", myFileTarget);
myFileTarget.FileName = LogFile;
myFileTarget.Layout = LogFileLayout;
myFileTarget.AutoFlush = true;

//Archive specifics
var token = "{#}";
var archiveFileName = $"{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(LogFile)}.{token}.{Path.GetExtension(LogFile)}";
myFileTarget.ArchiveFileName = archiveFileName;
myFileTarget.ArchiveNumbering = ArchiveNumberingMode.Rolling;
myFileTarget.ArchiveEvery = toFileArchivePeriod(LogStyle);
myFileTarget.EnableFileDelete = true;
myFileTarget.MaxArchiveFiles = TTL; //Time to Live
myFileTarget.DeleteOldFileOnStartup = true;
```

To simulate that a lot of logs already exists, I create a range of logs with the same structure as the ArchiveFileName above:

```
LogFileName = "LogTTLDailyTest.log";
LogStyle = "daily";
LogTTL = 5; //Time To Live

//Arrange old filelogs
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var filename = $"LogTTLDailyTest.{i}.log";
    File.WriteAllText(TestLogsDirectory + filename, "UNITTEST");
    var creationTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays((i + 1)* -1);
    File.SetCreationTime(TestLogsDirectory + filename, creationTime);
    File.SetLastWriteTime(TestLogsDirectory + filename, creationTime);
}
```

But when I write a log to nlog via my Log system it does not see the old log files I created and therefore do not delete them. It does however clean up the old current log file, so deleting files work:

```
NLog: 2017-07-20 12:54:20.7434 Info Closing old configuration.
NLog: 2017-07-20 12:54:20.7434 Info Found 36 configuration items
NLog: 2017-07-20 12:54:20.7594 Info Found 36 configuration items
NLog: 2017-07-20 12:54:26.9157 Info Deleting old archive file: 'C:\<projectpath>\bin\Debug\unittestlogsea984b05-3c33-4142-9d1a-c900bad89006\LogTTLDailyTest.log'.
```

My current theory is that the nlog sees the old logs but have some kind of validation process of the contents of the files which I only fill up with "UNITTEST" as content, but I haven't been able to "restart" nlog or force it to see the logs.

Hope you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no issue here, just me not setting the test up right. What I forgot is that rolling does not delete, but merely rename all files to the next rolling number. The last file in this rolling manner is deleted. Any other file is ignored by nlog. I also forgot to set my current log file a day back. This meant that nlog saw I had a current file that was not a day old. But because i had DeleteOldFileOnStartup activated it deleted that file.

So, to fix my mistake I made sure I only create as many files as I needed or less and made sure the latest file did not have a rolling number and was a day old. I also removed the DeleteOldFileOnStartup option. The Nlog is now doing what I expect it to do flawlessly.